# Apache Kafka - Consumer Fundamentals

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer

I have to use Apache Kafka to connect to the brokers of my firm. The problem is that I never used this technology before, and this is something that I need to clarify a little bit.

Actually, I created a "local" Kafka with a Zookeeper / Server / Consumer that works with the command

```
~/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic testGaultier --from-beginning
```

I'm now in another case where the Server / Producer are already managed by another person. I just have to create a consumer.

Is it necessary to download the entire package of Kafka to create the consumer or is there another way? I'd like to only make the recuperation of the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use console consumer then it is exactly the same as you did for local instance, but now specify zookeeper and topic name of the kafka server when you start consumer.

Or if you want to create a custom consumer you can use a Java consumer [API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerapi) or google for an API for another language.

In the first case you have to download Kafka package, since it has all the necessary scripts and classes. For second case there is no need to do this.